# Prove $A - (B - C) = (A - B) \cup (A \cap B \cap C)$.

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

> Prove $A - (B - C) = (A - B) \cup (A \cap B \cap C)$.

I tried from right to left but I do not have anything concrete. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The statement IS correct.

Note that $B-C = B-(B \cap C) = B \cap (B \cap C)^c$ thus $$A-(B-C) = A \cap (B \cap (B \cap C)^c)^c = A \cap (B^c \cup (B \cap C)) = (A\cap B^c) \cup (A \cap B \cap C).$$

And there is your answer.

Comment: How is $C = (B \cap C)$? I started from the right side but I stop at $(B - B) \cup (B - C)$

Comment: We do not have $C=(B \cap  C)$. We have $B - C = B - (B\cap C)$. It is easily shown by expanding it out. But just think of it intuitively. A Venn diagram might help.

Comment: Here is the expansion: $B\cap (B\cap C)^c = B \cap (B^c \cup C^c) = (B\cap B^c) \cup (B \cap C^c) = B \cap C^c$. But I think it is much better if you just think of it intuitively. You are taking $C$ out of $B$. So the only part that matters is the part of $C$ that was in $B$.

Comment: @epiliam.  Do you see where the logic is wrong in the other answer?

Comment: The maths wasn't wrong, just the conclusion. The final expression they wrote was valid, but their conclusion was not.

Answer (score 1):

I notated manipulations of the left hand side as $L$ and of the right hand side as $R$.

Expanding the LHS using that $A - B = A \cap B^c$, it is
$$A\cap \left( B \cap C^c \right)^c \tag {L1}$$

Use De Morgan's laws to get $$A \cap \left( B^c \cup C \right) \tag {L2}$$

Using similar logic for the RHS, it is
$$(A \cap B^c) \cup (A \cap B \cap C) \tag {R1}$$

This can be slightly condensed since $\left( A \cap B\right) \cup \left(A \cap C\right) = A\cap \left(B \cup C\right)$, so it simplifies to $$A \cap \left( B^c \cup \left( B \cap C \right) \right) \tag {R2}$$

All that is needed is to show that $$B^c \cup C = B^c \cup \left( B \cap C \right)$$

Take the complement and apply De Morgan's on both sides to get $$B \cap C^c = B \cap (B^c \cup C^c)$$

The right side can be expanded as $\left( B \cap B^c \right) \cup \left( B \cap C^c \right)$, which is $B \cap C^c$. Therefore, the left side is equal to the right side.

Comment: There is a mistake at $R2$. Your end result is $R3 \ne L2$ (one has a $\cap$ the other a $\cup$).

Comment: @epiliam Thanks for pointing this out! I fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

My view - without using complements : left side gives:
$$ x \in A \land (x \notin B \lor x \in C)$$
and right side gives
$$(x \in A \land x \notin B) \lor (x \in A \land x \in B \land x \in C  ) \Leftrightarrow \\
x \in A \land \big[x \notin B \lor (x \in B \land x \in C  )\big] \Leftrightarrow \\
x \in A \land (x \notin B \lor x \in C)
$$